# Do I need a visa for UK If I am British citizen travelling on foreign passport

Tags: visas, uk, passports

I have British passport which recently expired. The lag time for renewal means it will not be  ready for my holiday to Britain. Am told by visa office I don't need visa because I am citizen. But I will be travelling on my other passport (which stand alone needs a visa?

Comment: Hi, can you confirm if you have the expired passport with you in person?

Answer (score 1):

As a citizen you don't need a visa to enter the UK, since you have a legal right to do so. You would need evidence of citizenship, but an expired passport is one possible mechanism to do this. Since your second nationality is one which would require a visa, your biggest difficulty may be convincing your transportation company (airline/ferry company etc) to let you board in the first place.

Comment: *Since your second nationality is one which would require a visa, your biggest difficulty may be convincing your transportation company (airline/ferry company etc) to let you board in the first place.* Airlines all outsource their validation of documentation. Using an expired passport as evidence of nationality is not especially unusual, and is almost certain to be accepted.

Comment: As I recall, the UK explicitly accepts expired passports, and this fact is reflected in timatic.  If that is correct then it shouldn't be difficult to convince an airline to let the passenger board.